# PowerShell Checks Script Output to HTML Issue

Tags: html, powershell, scripting

I have a checks script which I am converting to output to HTML.

It has a function that checks a websites response time. I can't for the life of me get the output to show in HTML. Any ideas?

```
# Function to check external website content
function websitecheck($object) {
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$output = ""
$startTime = get-date
$output = $webClient.DownloadString($object)
$endTime = get-date
if ($output -like "*Test*" -or "*Testing*") {
 "Success`t`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t`t" + ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds" + "`t" + $object
} 
 else {
   "Fail`t`t" + $startTime.DateTime + "`t`t" + ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds" + "`t" + $object
 }
}

#External Website Check Function
Write-Host "External Website Checks"
Write-Host ""
$html = $html + @"
websitecheck "http://www.website01.com"
websitecheck "http://www.website02.com"
"@
Write-Host "========================="
Write-Host ""
```

Thanks

Comment: what is `$html` ? the first time you declared it, you equal it to itself... also, if you just need a table, you can create objects in your `websitecheck` function and use `ConvertTo-Html` to convert an array of those objects to a html-page with a table.

Comment: $html is declared earlier in the script, its rather large to post the entire script here.

Comment: okey. still need more. is $html a string variable with pure html code that you manually save to a file?  but as a solution:  try `$html = $html + @"
$(websitecheck "http://www.website01.com")
$(websitecheck "http://www.website02.com")
"@`  the call to the function is an expression, and needs to be wrapped. if it works, I'll add it as an answer when you verify

Comment: Works great, add it as the answer so I can mark completed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your expressions inside the here-string so they execute prior to being added to the stirng. Ex.

```
$html = $html + @"
$(websitecheck "http://www.website01.com")
$(websitecheck "http://www.website02.com")
"@
```